# mysql fast select query without reading all db

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a large database with two tables: stat and total.

The example of the relation is the following:

STAT:

```
|   ID   |  total event |
+--------+--------------+
|   7    |  2           |
|   8    |  1           |
```

TOTAL:

```
|ID | Event        |
+---+--------------+
| 7 | "hello"      |
| 7 | "everybody"  |
| 8 | "hi"         |
```

This is a very simplified version; also consider that STAT table could have 500K records, and for each STAT I can have about 200 TOTAL rows.

Currently, if I run a simple `SELECT` query in table TOTAL the system is terribly slow.

Could anyone help me with some advice for the creation of the TOTAL table? Is it possible to say to MySQL that the `id` column is already sorted so that there is no reason to scan all the rows till the end where, for example, `id=7`?

Comment: What hardware are you running this database on, briefly? If it's a shared Linux web server, it might be time to upgrade!

Comment: at the moment is running on a PC ..the database is the output of a program that is run locally

Comment: Right. Bear in mind that databases on desktop hardware tend to perform quite badly in comparison to similar hardware set up as a server. (Side note: it is helpful to state OS, CPU and RAM details as an answer to this kind of question, so as to give the reader an idea of your machine spec - though in this case it's not too important!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an index, and furthermore you can partition your table.

Comment: and then if I do a partition I should also add another table with the mapping right?   with mapping I intend :   in partition number 1 I have ids from 1 to 10 for example..

Comment: no..The table which is having huge data, u can partition that into small chunks, but do remember, the column on which u are partitioning the table should always be in a clause in the where clause of every query on that table. Otherwise it will scan all the partitions

Comment: Half a million records is probably too early to partition, imo. Wait until you've got 10M records `:)`

Comment: @halfer: Well said, but I was being futuristic so I have wrote "furthermore"

Comment: could you make an example on how doing the select query, please?

Comment: well I think i'll reach about 9M records so the "furthermore" idea is appreciated ^^

Comment: Look, if you are partitioning a table having the logged_date as a columnx(whenever there is an insert the logged_date has the currenttime) in a table:

Then your every query ::
select column1, column2
from table 
where columnx between(to,from)

Comment: @SashiKant: sure, but being futuristic is needlessly complicating things for a beginner. Just do indexes and primary keys to start with!

Comment: @halfer:: user1083700 may b new to stackoverflow doesn't mean that he is new to DB or MYSQL, and I thought telling him about partitioning is not confusing, but increasing his options LIST..

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `INDEX(ID)` to your tables (both), if you did not already.
2. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TOTAL WHERE ID=7` -> if `ID` is *indexed*, this will be fast.

Comment: THe ID is key is a primary key here, and it has been automatically indexed

Comment: @SashiKant: `TOTAL (ID)` is not unique, so it can't be the Primary Key.

Comment: IN 
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TOTAL WHERE ID=7 -> if ID is indexed, this will be fast", you are considering the ID which is a primary key

Comment: sorry for not having competence at all..as you can easily understand from the question :D      but if i index the columns, can I have duplicates?        and also..   what if I would do a select WHERE event='xxx' ?    same slow search right?

Comment: `ID` can't be PRIMARY in TOTAL because it has multiple occurrences, as ypercube mentioned

Comment: @user1083700 you can have duplicates if the key is not `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` (regular index is not adding uniqueness constraint)

Answer (score 0):

As per @ypercube's comment, tables are not stored in a sorted state, so one cannot "tell" this to the database. However you can add an index on tables to make them faster to search.

One important thing to check - it looks like `TOTAL.ID` is intended as a foreign key - if so, the table `TOTAL` should have a primary key called `ID`. Rename the existing column of that name to `STAT_ID` instead, so it is obvious what it is a foreign key for. Then add an index on `STAT_ID`.

Lastly, as a point of style, I recommend that you make your table and column names case-insensitive, and write them in lower-case. It makes it easier to read SQL when keywords are in upper case, and database objects are in lower.